# How to make ImageView invisible when multiple clicked (ListView)

Tags: java, android, listview, imageview

I want to hide `ImageView` when multiple click in `Listview`.

I did like this:

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
            final int checkedCount = listView.getCheckedItemCount();
            mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Selected");
            if(checked) {
                imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(final ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                    return false;

                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater menuInflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_mode, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**But there was only one item invisible and I was getting error.**

If anything, I have custom adapter for `ListView`. Thanks.

Comment: What is your error message ?

Comment: What is imageView? Since you're only setting this one imageView invisible, its obvious that only one will beome invisible.